# getting /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2c while running make

Tags: compile

I am trying to compile `UMFPACK`. I am running make and getting the below error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2c
```

So I have installed `2clib-devel.x86_64` package.Then I ran `make clean` and `make` ,but still getting the same error. Any help will be appropriated